# How to save in CSV file "rowcount of query execution" in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have created a test plan in Jmeter which executes certain queries and store elapsed time in csv file. I need to save row count against each sampler request. How can I achieve this?

Below is my CSV file configuration

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use any of JMeter Listeners to store test results, [they don't add any value and create memory and disk IO overhead instead](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing). You should be [running your tests in command-line non-GUI mode like](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   and when your test is finished either open `result.jtl` file with the listener of your choice or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from it.
2. Coming back to your question. Given you have a JMeter Variable holding some "interesting" value and you would like this variable value to be added to test results just define `sample_variables` property and put the variable name there. For example, if you have JMeter Variable called `rowcount` add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=rowcount
   ```

   and next time you run your test you will see an extra column in the .jtl results file called `rowcount` holding the variable value for each and every sampler. See [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) User Manual chapter for more details.

Comment: Great! Let me implement it.