# Jmeter - How to get the rowcount of a callable statement in your result csv file output

Tags: jmeter

I have created a testplan in Jmeter, where I run a series of callable statements. I want to measure the performance of these callable statements. I run these callable statements (stored procedures) on Sybase and Oracle, and compare the performance.

I would like to store the rowcount that is returned by each callable statement in the result.jtl / result.csv file that is generated during the run.

I have looked on Stackoverflow whether this question was already asked, and I found the following: [How to save in CSV file "rowcount of query execution" in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034141/how-to-save-in-csv-file-rowcount-of-query-execution-in-jmeter)

I have repeated the exact same solution for my testplan, but the rowcount is populated as NULL in my jtl file. The solution provided in the link above applies to queries, and probably not for callable statements.

Does anyone know how to store the rowcount for callable statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between normal select statements and procedures

1. Define a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) called i.e. `myVar` in "Variable Names" section of the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler

   [image]
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=myVar_#
   ```
3. That's it, now you have a `${myVar_#}` JMeter Variable holding the number of rows returned by the stored procedure and it will be written to the .jtl results file for each and every sample result

   [image]

More information: [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter/)

Comment: Apologies for the late response (I was out of office), but thanks for your reply Dmitri. It works now!